# Excel custom formatting for negative numbers

Tags: excel

How would I create an Excel custom formatting option that displays negative numbers as zero?

Right now I'm using this `##;"0";0` but it ignores values such as 0.25, 0.85 and 0.366666667 (only seems to acknowledge 1 or greater).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many decimal values are you looking to use? `##` will not show any, so `0.2` will become `<empty>`, but `##.#` will return `.2`.

To round out the format based on what you're looking for, on my own machine I used `##.###;"0";0`. If you want the leading zero (`0.2` vs. `.2`), then use `#0.###;"0";0`.